# Why does contenteditable caret with tags go behind each tag in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: javascript, html, css, microsoft-edge, contenteditable

I am creating a contenteditable component for angular2+ which should be editable anywhere. With anywhere I mean at the start of a tag, between tags and end of tag (not within the actual tag text). Here is the code with pre-loaded data from the API.

```
<div id="txt" contenteditable="true">
  <span id="annyoing-html" contenteditable="false">
    <span class="badge">I AM ANNOYING</span>
  </span>
  <span id="annyoing-html" contenteditable="false">
    <span class="badge">I AM ANNOYING TOO</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Full demo code:

https://jsfiddle.net/9kqkbuvr/5/

To see how it should work, open it with Chrome or Opera.

Comment: I've made a [demo](https://jsbin.com/maluxog/edit?html,css,output) which shows the bug in Edge (`v44`)

Answer (score 0):

mmm.... padding is not white-space... it should not be selectable... I am not sure which interpretation is correct. A workaround is to place a space between the two non-editable spans.

```
<div id="txt" contenteditable="true">
  <span id="annyoing-html" contenteditable="false">
    <span class="badge">I AM ANNOYING</span>
  </span>&nbsp;
  <span id="annyoing-html" contenteditable="false">
    <span class="badge">I AM ANNOYING TOO</span>
  </span>
</div>
```